# NuGet target framework vs. MSBuild version

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuspec

I'm building a NuGet package that uses the new features in NuGet 2.5 to automatically update the project file to include a `*.props` and `*.targets` file to add support for custom build steps. Currently these files are included in the NuGet package under the following paths:

- `/build/net35`: These are the `.props` and `.targets` files for projects using **MSBuild 3.5** (i.e. Visual Studio 2008), regardless of which target framework their project targets.
- `/build/net40`: These are the `.props` and `.targets` files for projects using **MSBuild 4.0** (i.e. Visual Studio 2010-2012), regardless of which target framework their project targets.

Unfortunately NuGet does not appear to behave the way I expected, and the `/build/net35` folder is getting used for projects using MSBuild 4.0 (Visual Studio 2012) that target .NET 3.5. How can I restructure the package to separate my build customizations based upon which version of MSBuild the project uses, and not by what the target framework is?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by separating the original `Antlr4` package into three separate packages:

1. `Antlr4.Runtime`: This package contains the runtime libraries for each supported target framework.
2. `Antlr4`: This package contains only the tools and build configuration for MSBuild 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010+). It depends on the `Antlr4.Runtime` package. The build files are placed in `/build` instead of the original `/build/net40`.
3. `Antlr4.VS2008`: This package contains only the tools and build configuration for MSBuild 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008). It depends on the `Antlr4.Runtime` package. The build files are placed in `/build` instead of the original `/build/net35`.

With these packages separated, users install either `Antlr4` or `Antlr4.VS2008` (depending on which version of MSBuild they are using), and NuGet will properly install everything.